# Comparing an element of a string array with a string

Tags: c++, arrays, string

So, while practicing strings i came across this question that gave me, "n" number of strings and it asked me to output strings in increasing alphabetical order.
Example :

```
Input>>  
4           // number of string  
abcdef ghi  // string 1  
ccdef       // string 2    
bcdcas      // string 3  
xcxvb       // string 4  
vxzxz       // string 5
```

This will output only strings 1,2,4 because we have to print string in an increasing alphabetical way.
string 1 < string 2 < string 4.
(string 3 is smaller than string 2, and hence the output)

So i coded the problem without using string array and it worked, but when i applied the same approach the output was not correct.

Maybe i don't know something about string array that you guys can help me with.

Here is the code for you guys :

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    string array[n];
    cin.ignore();
    for(int i=0; i<n;i++){
        getline(cin , array[i]);
    }
    cout << array[0] << endl;
    string maximum;
    for(int i = 0; i<n; i++){
        maximum = array[0];
        if(array[i] > maximum){
            maximum = array[i];
            cout << maximum << endl;
        }


    }
}
```

Here is the code that worked without any problems:

```
 using namespace std;

 int main()
 {
   ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
   int n;
   cin >> n;
   string text;
   cin.ignore();
   string max = "";
   for(int i=0; i<n;i++){
      getline(cin , text);
      if(text>max){
         max = text;
         cout << text << endl;
      }
   }

}
```

Comment: Move `maximum = array[0];` outside for loop.

Comment: @rafix07 ohhh, thanks. I feel like this question needed not to be asked. Sorry

Comment: Why you want only 3 strings to be printed? In alphabetical order you would have strings 1, 3, 2, 5, 4.

Comment: We do not have to sort them. We have to print the strings from the given sequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used your working code as a starting point. Try to avoid c-style arrays and use one of the C++ containers (like `std::vector`) instead.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    int n;
    std::string text;
    std::vector<std::string> array;

    std::cout << "Enter number of strings: ";
    std::cin >> n;
    std::cin.ignore();

    for(int i=1; i<=n;i++) {
        std::cout << "Enter string " << i << ": ";
        std::getline(std::cin, text);

        // check if we already have stored anything in the array and
        // then check if text is <= than the last element in the array.
        // if so, continue will skip to the next iteration in the for-loop

        if(array.size()>0 && text<=array.back()) continue;

        std::cout << "saved " << text << "\n";
        array.emplace_back(std::move(text));
    }

    std::cout << "All saved strings:\n";
    for(auto& s : array) {
        std::cout << s << "\n";
    }
}
```